# wp_kses not accepting style attribute for div

Tags: wordpress, validation

```
 $string = $_POST['data']['container']['box'];
    $allowed = array(
        'div' => array 
                (
                    "style" => array(),
                    "class" => array(),
                    "entrance" => array()
                ),
        'p' => array
                (
                    "class" => array(),
                    "style" => array(),
                    "id" => array()
                ),
        'a' => array
                (
                    "href" => array(),
                    "class" => array()
                ),
        'h1' => array
                (
                    "style" => array(),
                    "id" => array()
                ),
        'hr' => array
                (
                    "class" => array(),
                    "style" => array()
                )
        );
    $sanitizedBox = wp_kses($string,$allowed);
```

This is my code for wp_kses. Everything looks fine for the output except that the element `div` does not receive the `style` attribute. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you log here your html code that's generated by `$string` using `var_dump($string)`?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress checks the styles within `style`, and will still strip the attribute if none of them are whitelisted. See [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173526/why-is-wp-kses-not-keeping-style-attributes-as-expected/195433#195433) for additional information.